# Is it possible to override a method from interface at runtime?

Tags: java, reflection, confluence

I wonder if it is possible to override a method from an interface. I'm developing a plugin application for Confluence Data Center, and I need to maintain backward compatibility with the older version of Confluence, some of the interfaces are only available in the latest version of Confluence SDK, and I need to implement it dynamically(check the version, if it's an old version, use old interface)

this is the interface I need to implement:

```
public interface SiteSearchPermissionsQueryFactory {
    SearchQuery create();
}
```

I have a class implementing the interface:

```
public class SiteSearchPermissionQueryFactory implements SiteSearchPermissionsQueryFactory {
    final private SearchQuery searchQuery;

    public SiteSearchPermissionQueryFactory(SearchQuery searchQuery){
        this.searchQuery = searchQuery;
    }

    @Override
    public SearchQuery create() {
        return searchQuery;
    }
}
```

As `SiteSearchPermissionsQueryFactory` is a new interface and only available on the latest version of Confluence SDK, and now I need to implement this interface and its override method `create()` dynamically on runtime(if my plugin application runs on latest version of Confluence).
I can check the instance of `SiteSearchPermissionsQueryFactory` like this:

```
public static SearchQuery getCompatibleQuery() {
        try {
            Class<?> permissionQueryFactory = Class.forName("SiteSearchPermissionsQueryFactory");
            Object instance = Proxy.newProxyInstance(permissionQueryFactory.getClassLoader(), new Class<?>[]{permissionQueryFactory}, new InvocationHandler() {
                @Override
                public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                    //Handle the invocations
                    if(method.getName().equals("create")){
                        return 1;
                    }
                    else return -1;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
          return null;
        }
    }
```

But I have no idea how to override the `create()` method. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked into proxies?

Comment: Yes, but I can't find any way to do the overriding